# jquery plugin that supports images, videos & pdfs

Tags: jquery, plugins

Can anybody suggest me a jquery lightbox plugin that supports images, videos and pdfs.

I searched a lot didn't find any plugin that supports all three types of files.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: don't forget to validate the answer if you found it relevant. :)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at a plugin that supports

- previews
- drag and drop
- multiple uploads

[krajee - Link](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo#ajax-uploads)

Is from far the best.